# Does it make any sense to specialize a function template with universal reference parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

For a template function, we can specialize it as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T t) {}

// specialization for int
template <>
void func(int t) {}
```

However, I'm not sure how to specialize a template function with universal reference (a name from [Meyers' book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996)).

```
// template function with universal reference
template <typename T>
void func(T &&t) {}
```

I think simply replacing `T` with `int` doesn't make it a specialization:

```
template <>
void func(int &&t) {}
```

Since the template function can accept both lvalue and rvalue, while the 'specialized' one can only accept rvalue.

Should I also define a 'specialization' with lvalue reference?

```
// 'specialization' for lvalue reference
template <>
void func(int &t) {}
```

And the two 'specializations' make the specialization for the original template function? Or does it make any sense to have a specialization for it?

Comment: are you saying that you want to specialise func for all expressions of an int argument, i.e. int, int&, int&&, const int&  ?

Comment: Could you maybe go up a bit and describe in higher level what you're trying to solve?

Comment: Specializations for any of those specific examples doesn't make a ton of sense, as opposed to just flat-out *overloads*.

Comment: @RichardHodges I want to specialize it for `int&` and `int&&`. For your reminding, maybe also `const int&`. I think `int` is out of consideration, since in function `void func(T &&t)`, `t` can never to an `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specializing function templates is rarely a good idea.  Very rarely.  It looks like a mixture of template class specialization and overloading, but works like neither.

Functions have overloads.  Use those.

If overloading does not get the exact behaviour you want, use a helper function with tag dispatching based overloading, or forward to a class.

In this case, it could be as simple as:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T&&){}
void func(int){}
```

Or:

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T>tag{};
namespace details{
  template <class T, class U>
  void func(tag_t<T>, U&&){}
  template <class U>
  void func(tag_t<int>, U&&){}
}
template <class T>
void func(T&&t){
  return details::func(tag<std::decay_t<T>>, std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When T is matched against a type it can be any of these (this is a non-exhaustive list):

```
int
int&
int const&
int&&
int volatile&
int volatile const&
```

... and so on.

Specialising in this case does not make much sense because we'd have to anticipate and write specialisations which match all use cases.

But maybe `func` actually represents a concept of some function which can be applied against a universal reference.

In which case what we'd probably do is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Type>
struct func_op
{
  template<class T> void operator()(T&& t) const
  {
    // default implementation
  }
};

template <typename T>
void func(T&& t) 
{
  func_op<std::decay_t<T>> op;
  return op(std::forward<T>(t));
}


// now specialise the operation for all classes of int

template<>
struct func_op<int>
{
  template<class T> void operator()(T&& t) const
  {
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>(), 
                  "not an int!");
    std::cout << "some kind of operation on int" << t << std::endl;
  }
};



int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  const int b = 6;
  const volatile int c = 7;
  volatile int d = 8;
  func(a);
  func(b);
  func(c);
  func(d);
  func(std::move(a));
  func(std::move(b));
  func(std::move(c));
  func(std::move(d));

}
```

Here, the `Type` template argument in the specialisation of `func_op<>` represents the general value type. We then provide a templated `operator()` in order to provide the universal reference-based implementation.

The `T` in `func<T>` is converted into a 'general value type' by `std::decay_t` - which has the effect of stripping off all const, volatile and reference modifiers and leaving us with a raw type (e.g. int).

We could further specialise or overload operator() if we wished to provide special handling for (for example) const int refs.